# Loop over List of ints vs List of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to know why changing a variable in python's for loop changes dictionary element but not list?
In another word I want to compare following codes with each other, why the output is different?

```py
list1 = [10, 20]
for item in list1:
    item += 1
print(list1)
# Output: [10, 20]

dict = [{"Age":10}, {"Age":20}]
for item in dict:
    item["Age"] += 1
print(dict)
# Output: [{'Age': 11}, {'Age': 21}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't change because in case of list you changed value of `int` which is immutable in python, so changing `item` won't affect it's original value in list, while in second case you modified `dict` object which is mutable, so your change was applied to original object. For example, following code with list will work:

```
list = [{}, {}]
for item in list:
    item['Age'] = 1
print(list)
```

Output:

> [{'Age': 1}, {'Age': 1}]